# why does my recyclerview not reset when i delete text fast in my searchbar android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

i have a search functionality in my app and although is it very limited due to the firebase firestore database queries, i managed to make it work to find string that match the beginning of the user's input.

now everything works fine, even when i write a string for instance "starbucks" and i slowly delete it character by character it resets my recyclerView to full shops available and not only starbucks.

but when i delete quickly (press down on the back button in the keyboard), it stops at that specific shop and doesnt refresh.

what is causing this?

here is my search adapter:

```
 public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.SearchAdapterViewHolder> {

public Context c;
public ArrayList<Shop> arrayList;
public SearchAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<Shop> arrayList){
    this.c = c;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position){
    return position;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SearchAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shop_item,parent,false);
    return new SearchAdapterViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Shop shop = arrayList.get(position);

    holder.list_name.setText(shop.getName());
    String removeBraces = shop.getLocation();
    String removeLeftBrace = removeBraces.replace("[","");
    String removeRightBrace = removeLeftBrace.replace("]","");
    holder.list_location.setText(removeRightBrace);
    holder.list_overallRating.setText(""+shop.getRatings());
    holder.setHeaderImage(shop.getShopHeaderImg());
    holder.list_profileImage(shop.getShopProfileImg());



    holder.cardLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("shopModel", shop);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}



public class SearchAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private RelativeLayout cardLayout;
    private TextView list_name;
    private TextView list_location;
    private TextView list_overallRating;
    private ImageView header_img;
    private ImageView list_profileImage;

    public SearchAdapterViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        list_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_name);
        list_location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_location);
        list_overallRating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_overallRating);
        header_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.header_img);
        list_profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_profileImage);
        cardLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardLayout);
    }
    public void setHeaderImage(final String Image) {
        final ImageView headerImg = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.header_img);
        Picasso.get().load(Image).into(headerImg);

    }
    public void list_profileImage( final String image) {
        final ImageView profileImg = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_profileImage);
        Picasso.get().load(image).into(profileImg);

    }
}

}
```

here is my addTextChangeListener:

```
searchShops.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if(!s.toString().isEmpty()){
                searchInDB(s.toString().toLowerCase());
            }else{
               searchInDB("");
            }
        }
    });
```

and here is my searchInDB function:

```
private void searchInDB(final String s) {

 

firebaseFirestore.collection("Shops").orderBy("searchName").startAt(s).endAt(s+"\uf8ff").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

         @Override
         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
             if(task.isSuccessful()){
                 QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = task.getResult();
                 if(!querySnapshot.isEmpty()){
                     arrayList.clear();
                     for(QueryDocumentSnapshot DocumentSnapshot : querySnapshot) {
                         final Shop shop = DocumentSnapshot.toObject(Shop.class);
                         arrayList.add(shop);

                     }
                     SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
                     recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
                     searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

             }else{
                     arrayList.clear();


                }
             }else{

             }
         }


     });
```

Comment: What do you mean through "it stops at that specific shop and doesnt refresh."?

Comment: @AlexMamo i searched for lets say "new york coffe". it brings up new york coffee item in a (cardview). when i delete the text, it doesnt remove it and go back to the full list of shops i have

Comment: Have you tried to move that logic in `onTextChanged`?

Comment: yeah i did, but ill try again @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo yep still the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
if(!s.toString().isEmpty()){
                searchInDB(s.toString().toLowerCase());
            }else{
               searchInDB("");
            }
```

To

```
if(!s.toString().isEmpty()){
                searchInDB(s.toString().toLowerCase());
            }else{
               recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
            }
```

Comment: it works for a split second then stays on what i searched for.